# Annotating a Matplotlib Polycollection bar timeline

Tags: python, matplotlib

My question is: how to annotate a Matplotlib Polycollection bar chart when hovering over the bars using "motion_notify_event"? I have spent the day trying to make this work but I just cant get my head round a polycollection object and how to index it. Hopefully someone can help solve this, I have spent so much time on it I would hate to give up now!

A great solution to scatter, line and bar annotations using "motion_notify_event" is found in the link below:
[Possible to make labels appear when hovering over a point in matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7908636/possible-to-make-labels-appear-when-hovering-over-a-point-in-matplotlib)

However, the above solutions do not deal with a 'matplotlib.collections.polycollection' object. I am struggling to find ways of accessing the vertices and arrays held in this object using the code in the above solution. Is it possible to index the polycollection; use the index to access a string value in the original data; then annotate the position whilst hovering over it?

I have used a modified example of a Polycollection bar timeline from the below link which I have fused with the hover/annotate examples in the above link.
[How to individually label bars in Matplotlib plot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63307664/how-to-individually-label-bars-in-matplotlib-plot)

```
    import datetime as dt
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import matplotlib.dates as mdates
    from matplotlib.collections import PolyCollection

    data = [(dt.datetime(2018, 7, 17, 0, 15), dt.datetime(2018, 7, 17, 0, 30), 'sleep','nap_1'),
           (dt.datetime(2018, 7, 17, 0, 30), dt.datetime(2018, 7, 17, 0, 45), 'eat', 'snack_1'),
           (dt.datetime(2018, 7, 17, 0, 45), dt.datetime(2018, 7, 17, 1, 0), 'work', 'meeting_1'),
           (dt.datetime(2018, 7, 17, 1, 0), dt.datetime(2018, 7, 17, 1, 30), 'sleep','nap_2'),
           (dt.datetime(2018, 7, 17, 1, 15), dt.datetime(2018, 7, 17, 1, 30), 'eat', 'snack_2'), 
           (dt.datetime(2018, 7, 17, 1, 30), dt.datetime(2018, 7, 17, 1, 45), 'work', 'project_2')]

    cats = {"sleep" : 1, "eat" : 2, "work" : 3}
    colormapping = {"sleep" : "C0", "eat" : "C1", "work" : "C2"}

    verts = []
    colors = []
    for d in data:
        v =  [(mdates.date2num(d[0]), cats[d[2]]-.4),
              (mdates.date2num(d[0]), cats[d[2]]+.4),
              (mdates.date2num(d[1]), cats[d[2]]+.4),
              (mdates.date2num(d[1]), cats[d[2]]-.4),
              (mdates.date2num(d[0]), cats[d[2]]-.4)]
        verts.append(v)
        colors.append(colormapping[d[2]])

    bars = PolyCollection(verts, facecolors=colors)

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.add_collection(bars)
    ax.autoscale()
    loc = mdates.MinuteLocator(byminute=[0,15,30,45])
    ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(loc)
    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.AutoDateFormatter(loc))

    ax.set_yticks([1,2,3])
    ax.set_yticklabels(["sleep", "eat", "work"])

    annot = ax.annotate("", xy=(0, 0), xytext=(20, 20), textcoords="offset points",
      bbox=dict(boxstyle="round", fc="w"),
      arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="->"))
    annot.set_visible(False)


    def update_annot(ind):
        # how to index the polycollection? get_offsets causes an error
        pos = bars.get_offsets()[ind["ind"][0]] 
        # causes 'IndexError: index 5 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1'
        annot.xy = pos
        # If we can get an index, can we use it to access the original 'data' to get the 
        # string value at d[3] from data ('nap_1') and use it to annotate?
        text = ""

        annot.set_text(text)
        annot.get_bbox_patch().set_facecolor(cmap(norm(c[ind["ind"][0]])))
        annot.get_bbox_patch().set_alpha(0.4)


    def hover(event):
        vis = annot.get_visible()
        if event.inaxes == ax:
            cont, ind = bars.contains(event)
            if cont:
                update_annot(ind)
                annot.set_visible(True)
                fig.canvas.draw_idle()
            else:
                if vis:
                    annot.set_visible(False)
                    fig.canvas.draw_idle()

    fig.canvas.mpl_connect("motion_notify_event", hover)

    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to get to the desired data is a bit complicated, and can be found out by digging into the debugger:

- `bars.get_paths()` gives a list of `Path` objects (the polygons).
- this can be indexed to get to an individual bar
- `bars.get_paths()[ind].get_extents()` gives the bounding box of the bar
- `bars.get_paths()[ind].get_extents().get_points()` gives the lower left and the upper right point of the bounding box.

```py
import datetime as dt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
from matplotlib.collections import PolyCollection

data = [(dt.datetime(2018, 7, 17, 0, 15), dt.datetime(2018, 7, 17, 0, 30), 'sleep', 'nap_1'),
        (dt.datetime(2018, 7, 17, 0, 30), dt.datetime(2018, 7, 17, 0, 45), 'eat', 'snack_1'),
        (dt.datetime(2018, 7, 17, 0, 45), dt.datetime(2018, 7, 17, 1, 0), 'work', 'meeting_1'),
        (dt.datetime(2018, 7, 17, 1, 0), dt.datetime(2018, 7, 17, 1, 30), 'sleep', 'nap_2'),
        (dt.datetime(2018, 7, 17, 1, 15), dt.datetime(2018, 7, 17, 1, 30), 'eat', 'snack_2'),
        (dt.datetime(2018, 7, 17, 1, 30), dt.datetime(2018, 7, 17, 1, 45), 'work', 'project_2')]

cats = {"sleep": 1, "eat": 2, "work": 3}
colormapping = {"sleep": "C0", "eat": "C1", "work": "C2"}

verts = []
colors = []
for d in data:
    v = [(mdates.date2num(d[0]), cats[d[2]] - .4),
         (mdates.date2num(d[0]), cats[d[2]] + .4),
         (mdates.date2num(d[1]), cats[d[2]] + .4),
         (mdates.date2num(d[1]), cats[d[2]] - .4),
         (mdates.date2num(d[0]), cats[d[2]] - .4)]
    verts.append(v)
    colors.append(colormapping[d[2]])

bars = PolyCollection(verts, facecolors=colors)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.add_collection(bars)
ax.autoscale()
loc = mdates.MinuteLocator(byminute=[0, 15, 30, 45])
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(loc)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.AutoDateFormatter(loc))

ax.set_yticks([1, 2, 3])
ax.set_yticklabels(["sleep", "eat", "work"])

annot = ax.annotate("", xy=(0, 0), xytext=(20, 20), textcoords="offset points",
                    bbox=dict(boxstyle="round", fc="w"),
                    arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="->"))
annot.set_visible(False)

def update_annot(ind):
    pos = bars.get_paths()[ind].get_extents().get_points()[1]
    annot.xy = pos
    text = f"{data[ind][2]}: {data[ind][3]}"
    annot.set_text(text)
    # annot.get_bbox_patch().set_facecolor(colormapping[data[ind][2]])
    annot.get_bbox_patch().set_facecolor(bars.get_facecolors()[ind])
    annot.get_bbox_patch().set_alpha(0.4)

def hover(event):
    vis = annot.get_visible()
    if event.inaxes == ax:
        cont, ind = bars.contains(event)
        if cont:
            update_annot(ind["ind"][0])
            annot.set_visible(True)
            fig.canvas.draw_idle()
        else:
            if vis:
                annot.set_visible(False)
                fig.canvas.draw_idle()

fig.canvas.mpl_connect("motion_notify_event", hover)
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

Comment: Nice one Johan! Great explanation!